# Inserting several columns into another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following DataFrame df1:

```
name    course   yob     city
paul    A        1995    london
john    A        2005    berlin
stacy   B        2015    vienna
mark    D        2013    madrid
```

And also the following DataFrame df2:

```
name    height   occupation   
paul    185      student    
mark    162      pilot
```

I want to combine them to obtain:

```
name    course   height   occupation   yob     city
paul    A        185      student      1995    london
john    A        NaN      NaN          2005    berlin
stacy   B        NaN      NaN          2015    vienna
mark    D        162      pilot        2013    madrid
```

So the idea is I have df1, which is my main data structure, and I want to insert the columns of df2 (which only has information regarding some of the names) in a specific location in df1 (namely in this case between the columns course and yob). The ordering of the columns is important, and shouldn't be changed.

What would be the most straightforward/elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalized approach will be merge and then create a list with `df2.columns` excluding the matching columns in the middle of the list `df1.columns` and `reindex()`:

```
final=df1.merge(df2,on='name',how='left')
l=list(df1.columns)
s=l[:len(l)//2]+list(df2.columns.difference(df1.columns))+l[len(l)//2:]
#['name', 'course', 'height', 'occupation', 'yob', 'city']
```

Then use [`reindex()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+reindex&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+reindex&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2054j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on `axis=1`

```
final=final.reindex(s,axis=1)
print(final)
```

---

```
    name course  height occupation   yob    city
0   paul      A   185.0    student  1995  london
1   john      A     NaN        NaN  2005  berlin
2  stacy      B     NaN        NaN  2015  vienna
3   mark      D   162.0      pilot  2013  madrid
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear you want left or outer join.  here is simple way for left join

I am using first dataframe as df1 and second dataframe as df2  for result

```
import pandas as pd

df_result = pd.merge (left=df1, right=df2, how='left', on='name')
# Reorder the columns
df_result = df_result[["name", "course", "height", "occupation", "yob", "city"]]

print(df_result)
```

If you want outer join

```
df_result = pd.merge (left=df1, right=df2, how='outer', on='name')
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't worried about the type of join, since df2 in my case always has a subset of the names in df1. My only problem with your answer is that the ordering for the columns that I specified in my question wouldn't be preserved. I need to insert the columns of df2 between two specific columns of df1.

Comment: add stmt   df_result = df_result[['name', 'course',....]]   in the order you need